# How do I print character values of a string?

Tags: c

I am trying to print the value of each character in a string in this format:

> Code 2 in set 0 has value: 41 42
>
> Code 6 in set 0 has value: 41 42 43 44 45 46

I am trying to do this by:

```
printf("Code %d in set %d has value: %.*s\n", ndx, set, getCode(cs[set],ndx).size, getCode(cs[set],ndx).data);
```

But when I do this it prints the characters associated with the value rather than the value itself. How should I go about printing the data in the format specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing your array as a string. Instead loop through each character and print its decimal value:

```
int i;
printf("Code %d in set %d has value: ", ndx, set);
for (i = 0; i < getCode(cs[set],ndx).size ; i++) {
  printf("%d ", getCode(cs[set],ndx).data[i]);
}
puts(""); //print a newline
```

Comment: In another one of my printf, it is printing 00 instead of just 0, what format specifier would accomplish this?

Comment: printf("%02d", 0); would print 00

Comment: I am having the opposite problem, when my program prints 0 it is putting an extra leading 0. When I extend a code it will look something like "Code 2 in set 0 has value: 41 85," I then change this second garbage value with 0 as such: mySet->memBlock->data[mySet->memBlock->bytesUsed - 1] = 0; but the print outputs "Code 1 in set 0 has value: 23 00"

Comment: Are you 100% sure there's not a %02d or similar in your printf ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `%d` specifier:

```
char str[] = "Hello";
printf("%d\n", str[0]);  // Displays 72
printf("%d\n", str[1]);  // Displays 101
```